# Refresh item after modal dialog close in apex oracle

Tags: oracle-apex

I trying to refresh item after close modal dialog, I have a form region  , all item in  the form (select list) , one of these  item  named  (customer) and beside this item i have a link which you need this to create  new customer  , when the customer  not in the list , by click  on this link after that the modal dialog page open , i want after close the modal dialog refresh this item to get new value , how i can do that  or set directly the created value in list

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a dynamic action

Event -> Diaglog Closed -> True -> Refresh:

```
Dynmamic Action: 
When
    Event: Dialog Closed 
    Selection Type: Region
    Region: ....Customer

Action
    Action: Refresh
    Affected Elements: 
         Selection Type: Region
         Region: ....Customer
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but the new value didn't appear in select list, the region is sub region in form region, this region  it's static region, i used it only for design (item container)

Comment: When you change the affected Elements to the Region where the select list is included, what happens then?

Comment: Why set "Selection Type" to "Region"? Set it to "Item" and then set the select list you want to refresh. Let us know if that works (if you see the new value in the list). The next step will be to select that value after the refresh, but we'll tackle that next.

Comment: I will try that tomorrow and tell you what the result.

Comment: i tried that but the region and the item didn't refresh .

Comment: i tried refresh item by apex.event.trigger( "#myRegionStaticID", "apexrefresh" ); 
it's working fine . thanks for your support